# Can't select first row in dhtmlxGrid after sorting

Tags: grid, dhtmlx

I'm trying to select first row after grid sorting using the following code

```
dhtmlx.image_path='./codebase/imgs/';

var main_layout = new dhtmlXLayoutObject({
   parent:  document.body,
   pattern: "1C",
   cells: [{id: "a"}]
});

var selectionGrig = main_layout.cells('a').attachGrid();

with (selectionGrig){
   attachEvent("onAfterSorting", 
       function(index,type,direction){
          selectionGrig.selectRow(0);
       }
   );
   setIconsPath('./codebase/imgs/');
   setHeader("Show,Group,Date,Time,C1,S,C2,L,H");
   setColTypes("ch,ro,dhxCalendar,ro,coro,ro,ro,ro,ro");
   setColSorting('int,int,date,time,int,str,int,str,int');
   setDateFormat('%d %M %Y','%Y-%m-%d');
   updateFromXML('./data/tmp.xml', true,false, function(){selectionGrig.groupBy(1);});
   init();
 }
}
```

but it select always the same row after sorting whatever the position of this row but not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the next code from onAfterSorting callback

```
selectionGrig.selectRow( selectionGrid.rowsCol[0] );
```